Use boost::filesystem with std::ifstream?
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with C++ 20 and boost 1.71.0.
The following compiles without error and outputs the sample file content:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <filesystem>

int main() {
    boost::filesystem::path output_dir = boost::filesystem::path("/out/");
    boost::filesystem::path sample_file = output_dir / "sample.txt";
    std::ifstream ifs{sample_file};
    std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    std::cout << "Sample file content: " << std::endl << content << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

So how does this work? Is this boost::filesystem::path implicitly cast to std::string?
Is this safe to use?

The documentation for Boost Filesystem fstream indicates:

The C++ Standard Library's  header uses const char* to pass arguments representing file names, with that usage occurring seven times.


The Filesystem Library's fstream.hpp header provides equivalent components, in namespace boost::filesystem, except that the seven  const char* arguments have been replaced by const path& arguments.


The Filesystem Library's fstream.hpp header simply uses the  standard library components as base classes, and then redeclares constructors and open functions to take arguments of type const path& instead of const char*.

It's documented use is in the 2 minute tutorial, and the examples.

Dangit. I was just about to answer the same thing, but I couldn't find the right phrases. You got my upvote in any case.

They aren't using boost::filesystem::ifstream though, they're using std::ifstream

Doc says: (5) participates in overload resolution only if FsPath is std::filesystem::path.. But int this case this is not true :/ since FsPath is boost::filesystem::path.

@MarekR this answer isn't incorrect, you can use boost::filesystem::path to open boost::filesystem::ifstream it just doesn't answer this question as the OP is using std::ifstream

std::basic_fstream has a constructor which takes a templated FSPath type https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream
This overload should only accept std::filesystem::path but it looks like libstdc++ accepts any class which conforms to std::filesystem::path's interface. This is non-standard and doesn't compile with other standard libraries: https://godbolt.org/z/njr5s3har
You can fix this with the boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp header, but you'll have to change std::ifstream to boost::filesystem::fstream. A better fix is to just change to using std::filesystem which is mostly a drop in replacement for boost::filesystem.
